# Check var is NULL in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, if-statement, drop-table

I have a script that deletes all tables.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; 
SET @tables = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) INTO @tables
  FROM information_schema.tables 
  WHERE table_schema = 'mydb';

SET @tables = CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', @tables);
PREPARE stmt FROM @tables;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

It perfectly works only once - when at least one table exists.
Second run gives me an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1 SQL.sql 9 1

I am trying to use IF statement, but it still doesn't work:

```
IF @tables IS NOT NULL THEN
  SET @tables = CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', @tables);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @tables;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END IF;
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if @tables IS NOT NULL THEN
>       SET @tables = CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', @tables)' at line 1 SQL.sql 8 1

What is the correct way to use IF in this case?

Answer (score 2):

When you assign a value to a session variable and use the same in a query then
its value will replace the place holder. And due to the reason,

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) INTO @tables
```

becomes

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name) INTO NULL
```

which has no meaning at all.

Instead you should directly use the variable without pre setting its value.
So don't use

```
SET @tables = NULL;
```

And secondly, the statement blocks can't be compiled directly by database engine unless their scope is defined under a block. This usually is done using a stored procedure or a trigger. If within a procedure, they must be between `BEGIN` and `END`.

So the following is wrong:

```
IF @tables IS NOT NULL THEN
  SET @tables = CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', @tables);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @tables;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END IF;
```

You should follow a syntax defined for a stored procedure to use scoped variables.

Please refer to my answer to a similar question, as referred below:

1. [***MySQL Syntax error***.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13012859/767881)
2. Also refer to: [***Variables declaration and scope***](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/variables-in-stored-procedures.aspx).